# Taylor diagram with negative correlation (left quadrant)

Tags: r, plot, correlation, negative-number, openair

I am trying to plot a Taylor diagram in `R`. The data I am working with give negative correlations. These should be plotted on the left quadrant of a Taylor diagram, but this is not happening with the package I am using called `openair`.

It seems that this package does not have this option. I have searched for other options without much success.

Is there any other way I can make such a plot in R?

Here's a sample code,

```
library(openair)

# Generate some data
obs = runif(3, min=5, max=20)
mod1 = obs * -obs^2 # to give a negative correlations
mod2 = obs * obs^2

df = data.frame(obs,mod1,mod2)

# Plot the diagram
taylor1 = TaylorDiagram(df, obs = "obs", mod = "mod1",normalise=TRUE) # mod1 is not plotted

taylor2 = TaylorDiagram(df, obs = "obs", mod = "mod2",normalise=TRUE) # mod2 is plotted
```

Thanks, Michel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also [`taylor.diagram()`](https://rdrr.io/cran/plotrix/man/taylor.diagram.html) from `plotrix` package

```r
library(plotrix)

set.seed(20191130)

# Generate some data
obs = runif(3, min=5, max=20)
mod1 = obs * -obs^2 # to give a negative correlations
mod2 = obs * obs^2

# Plot the diagram
taylor.diagram(obs, mod1, pos.cor = FALSE, normalize = TRUE)
taylor.diagram(obs, mod2, add = TRUE, col = "blue", normalize = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad to help!